# Update model with data retrieved from backbone.sync call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model similar to this.

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: null,
    name: '',
    groups: []
  },
  addGroup: function(group) {
    return this.sync(
      'update',
      this,
      {url: this.url() + 'add_group', data: 'group=' + group}
    );
  }
}

UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extends({
  model: User,
  url: '/api/users'
});
```

The purpose behind this call is that adding the permission triggers all sorts of backend checks and other changes. The actual code, which I'm trying to not to expose here, demonstrates the need better.

The /api/users/add_group endpoint returns a new representation of the Users model, which I wish to have applied to the model with all of the appropriate events triggered. The best work-around I could find is this.

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: null,
    name: '',
    groups: []
  },
  addGroup: function(group) {
    model = this;
    return this.sync(
      'update',
      this,
      {
        url: this.url() + 'add_group',
        data: 'group=' + group,
        success: function() {model.fetch();}
      }
    );
  }
}
```

However, it feels like there is probably a better solution where I can call arbitrary endpoints and have the model updated with the returned data.

Comment: The ideal way should be to add the new group into `groups` property and call `model.save()`. The backend should identify new group and return the data that should be saved in model. Else group should be a model itself, and groups should be a collection.

Comment: My example did poor justice to the question I was trying to ask. However, after implementing some needed functionality to this model and its relationships to other models, this became mute anyways. Thanks for looking.